# CKSubscription error

Tags: swift, push-notification, icloud, cksubscription

Hi I'm trying to save a subscription to iCloud, I'm using this code :

```
func setupCKSubscriptions(){

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("sub") == false{

        let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "Quadri", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: .FiresOnRecordCreation)

        let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
        notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = NSLocalizedString("NEW_Q", comment: "")
        notificationInfo.shouldBadge = true

        subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

        let modifyOperation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [subscription], subscriptionIDsToDelete: nil)
        modifyOperation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock = {(_, _, errore) -> Void in

            if errore == nil{

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "sub")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

            }else{

                print(errore?.localizedDescription)
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: errore?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        }

        CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.addOperation(modifyOperation)

    }
}
```

and I get this error (only when I run the app with TestFlight):

> Failed to modify some subscriptions

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this one? Have the same issue here.